Are separate Google Workspace OAuth clients required for each SaaS tenant for SSO?
We operate a multi-tenant B2B SaaS application that only supports OAuth2+OIDC, not SAML. We have users who would like to use Google Workspace for SSO. They all log in at the same URL (i.e., there is no company1.mysass.com subdomain).
Quite a few other SaaS applications (e.g. 1, 2) have documentation instructing the user's IT staff to create a new Google Cloud Platform project, set up an OAuth consent screen and create OAuth credentials.
If we don't use any sensitive or restricted scopes or an app logo (all of which would require app verification), is there any reason that I shouldn't do the OAuth configuration (with user type: external and status: production) in one of our GCP projects to save our users' IT staff the hassle? It seems to work fine with a test Google Workspace domain.

Is this best practice? Nope. Will it work from a technical perspective? Sure. People click on all kinds of unverified stuff in this day and age. Since you're hosting the identity provider service, will your company be responsible if something happens (attack or a simpler operational issue such as customer not being able to sign in) - good questions to ask your lawyers.

@identigral Why do you say it's not a best practice? The OAuth consent screen doesn't show the "unverified" mark in this scenario. Google is the IdP host, we're just configuring part of it.
